# Launch Minecraft 1.7.2 From Batch File and change Username

Tags: command-line, java, batch, minecraft, username

Near the start of the year I made a series of little batch scripts allowing people to run minecraft off of their usbs and not leave anything on the computer (symlink from %appdata%/.minecraft to ./.minecraft, deletes symlink when game closes) I also made a script to allow players to do this and choose a username basically using
`SET /P UserName=Username:

java -cp ".minecraft\bin\*"; -Djava.library.path=".minecraft\bin\natives" net.minecraft.client.Minecraft %UserName% net.minecraft.LauncherFrame`
Now since the folders bin and natives were removed I cannot find out how to get this to work. I have tried the obvious (changing bin to \versions\1.7.2*) to no avail.
Any help? I want to try to keep it as simple as possible...

Comment: *I made a series of little batch scripts allowing people to run minecraft off of their usbs and not leave anything on the computer* Maybe you can ask your teacher for help?

Answer (score 1):

This is a batch script I have been working on. It is small and might not work. 
You need to place this in your .minecraft folder where the file launcher_profiles.json should be. All you need to do is enter a username, and then it will change text in a file named launcher_profiles.json. You will need to type in your current username or the username you last used for this to work. if you have forgotten, it will be placed in a text document called username.txt

```
    @echo off
    attrib -r launcher_profiles.json
    set /p cho1=Current_Username:
    set /p cho2=Username:
    echo %cho2% > username.txt
    powershell -Command "(gc launcher_profiles.json) -replace '%cho1%', '%cho2%' |Out-File launcher_profiles.json"
    pause
    attrib +r launcher_profiles.json
    pause
```

The -r attribute will get rid of the read-only access from the previous use of the batch file. After the batch file is done it will lock the file so that the minecraft launcher can't fix the code.
     If minecraft comes up asking you to login, delete the launcher_profiles.json file and start minecraft again. You will need to enter your credentials but if there was a problem, it should be fixed. Let me know if this doesn't work